# Altering DATE and posting it back tp phpmyadmin using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
header ('Refreash: 1;url=registrationform.php');
include 'dbconnect.php';
$id = $_POST['id'];
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];     
$DOB = $_POST['dob'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$memberTypeID = $_POST['memberTypeID'];
$Active = $_POST['Active'];
$sql = "UPDATE user SET firstName = '$firstName', lastName = '$lastName', email = '$email', password = '$password', DOB = '$DOB', gender = '$gender', telephone = '$telephone', memberTypeID = '$memberTypeID', Active = '$Active' WHERE userID = $id";
$result=mysql_query($sql)or die ("COULD NOT UPDATE USER!!");
```

This is the code i am using to enter the DOB back into the database, when entered it returns 0000-00-00.

Comment: what is the value of $DOB ?

Comment: Try  what is inside `$_POST['dob']`..

Comment: i.e.: what does `echo 'dob="', htmlentities($DOB), '"';` right before `$result = mysql_query...` print? Btw: your script is prone to sql injections, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and http://docs.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try what is inside `$_POST['dob']`..Also if the input value is not a valid date value then don't try to insert it. So if its not a valid value then make the dob as null and also make your table structure compatible to allow `NULL` values.If your `$_POST['dob']` doesn't  contains a valid date value in `YYYY-MM-DD` format then that value will be inserted as `0000-00-00` in the database.

So try something like the following

```
$DOB = NULL;
if(isset($_POST['dob']) && trim($_POST['dob']) != '')
 //make necessary validateions and assign the value
 $DOB = $newValue;//Assume $newValue contains new date value in YYYY-MM-DD format
```

Also don't use **mysql_** functions anymore since they are deprecated. Try using **mysqli_** functions and **prepare statements** because your code is vulnerable to sql injections